# Which main Star Trek characters haven't been transformed into other species?

Tags: star-trek

Which Star Trek characters who were main cast in their respective shows **haven't** been transformed into a species different from their usual one by any means? E.g. alien virus, cosmetic surgery for infiltration, holographic trickery, etc.

I would include Tasha Yar as a transformation because of [Sela](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sela) and the Enterprise-D's reaction to her. I wouldn't include [Ethan Philips' first appearance as a Ferengi](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Farek), but I would when Neelix was [made up to look like a Ferengi](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Grand_Proxy) in False Profits since the first was a separate character and the second was clearly Neelix in disguise. Basically, if the characters who know them best would recognise them as the same character (even mistakenly), they should be included.

I can't remember Dr Crusher or Worf ever being transformed into other species (OK, I just remembered [Genesis](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Genesis_(episode)) for Worf), but my memory could be faulty. I would prefer only screen appearances, not comics or books or other appearances.

Comment: So hypothetically, if Picard was dressed as a Christmas tree in a school play (assuming that Christmas still exists), that would count, assuming that it covered his face?

Comment: @Adamant - What about Riker becoming a Q?

Comment: Speaking of Q, [he turned Dr. Crusher into a dog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-uzciSGyZAg)

Comment: @Adamant - Christmas does appear to still exist since Picard was celebrating it in the Nexus (and since the Nexus is trying to convince you it's real it's safe to assume it didn't just create a hallucination of a forgotten 20th century fad). However since CJ asked for only on-screen appearances and I don't believe Picard ever did this on screen, I would say it doesn't count.

Comment: This list is probably going to be quite long

Comment: @orange - TNG I think you could argue that almost all of the senior crew except Wesley was transformed at one point or another. Less so in DS9 and Voyager, almost never in Enterprise, STD or STP

Comment: also LD and SNW. In DS9 it's also harder to define "main cast".

Comment: @OrangeDog - Not really. It's those that received "Main Cast" billing.

Comment: Made a list, there are 77 main cast characters across all the TV shows

Comment: Sela shouldn't count - she was Yar's daughter. Not Yar transformed. That inclusion conflates actor w/ character and expands / muddies the question

Comment: Worf is also disguised/transformed into a human-like alien in 'Homeward' (TNG season 7).

Comment: Neelix was also turned into Tuvix for most of an episode. Whatever you'd call that species, it wasn't pure Talaxian.

Comment: @CJDennis there are many comments on my answer that I don't think count, but you are in charge of clarifying the question

Comment: When you return to your capital ship to find your crew mutated to primitive creatures due to an oversight by your chief medical officer. I hate those days.

Answer (score 13):

Characters organised by TV show they had main cast billing. Repeats are omitted. Spoilers are unhidden.

Those in **bold** have never been visually transformed into another species on screen. Only one example is given to discount people.

### Star Trek

- James T. Kirk - disguised as Romulan in *The Enterprise Incident*
- **Spock**
- **Leonard McCoy**
- **Montgomery Scott**
- **Nyota Uhura**
- **Pavel Chekov**
- **Hikaru Sulu**

### Star Trek: The Animated Series

- **Christine Chapel**

### Star Trek: The Next Generation

- Jean-Luc Picard - disguised as a Romulan in *Unification*
- William Riker - disguised as a Mintakan in *Who Watches The Watchers*
- Geordi La Forge - transformed into Tarchanne in *Identity Crisis*
- Tasha Yar<sup>*</sup> - half-Romulan daughter in *Redemption*
- Worf - disguised as a Boraalan in *Homeward*
- Beverly Crusher - transformed into a dog in *True Q*
- Deanna Troi - disguised as a Romulan in *Face of the Enemy*
- Data - disguised as a Romulan in *Unification*
- **Wesley Crusher**

<sup>*</sup> counts by the question's clarifications, but I disagree

### Star Trek: Deep Space Nine

- Benjamin Sisko - disguised as a Klingon in *Apocalypse Rising*
- Odo - almost always when not in the Great Link
- Jadzia Dax - disguised as a human in *Trials and Tribble-ations*
- **Jake Sisko**
- Miles O'Brien - disguised as a Klingon in *Apocalypse Rising*
- **Quark**
- **Julian Bashir**
- Kira Nerys - disguised as a Cardassian in *Second Skin*
- **Ezri Dax**

### Star Trek: Voyager

- Kathryn Janeway - transformed repeatedly in *Threshold*
- Chakotay - disguised as a Vidiian in *Faces*
- B'Elanna Torres - assimilated by the Borg in *Unimatrix Zero*
- Tom Paris - transformed repeatedly in *Threshold*
- Kes - transforms into an energy being in *The Gift*
- Neelix - disguised as Ferengi in *False Profits*
- The Doctor - takes the appearance of Seven of Nine in *Body and Soul*
- Tuvok - assimilated by the Borg in *Unimatrix Zero*
- Seven of Nine - Borg implants removed until almost human in *The Gift*
- Harry Kim - Infected by Species 8472 in *Scorpion*

### Star Trek: Enterprise

- Jonathan Archer - transformed into a Loque'eque in *Extinction*
- **T'Pol**
- **Phlox**
- Malcolm Reed - disguised as a Suliban in *Detained*
- **Travis Mayweather**
- Hoshi Sato - transformed into a Loque'eque in *Extinction*
- **Charles "Trip" Tucker III**

### Star Trek: Discovery

- Michael Burnham - disguised as a Trill hologram in *Su'Kal*
- Saru - disguised as a human hologram in *Su'Kal*
- Voq - disguised as a human for most appearances
- **Paul Stamets**
- **Sylvia Tilly**
- **Gabriel Lorca**
- Hugh Culber - disguised as a Bajoran hologram in *Su'Kal*
- **Christopher Pike**
- **Nhan**
- **Cleveland "Book" Booker**
- **Jett Reno**
- **Adira Tal**

### Star Trek: Picard

- Agnes Jurati - assimilated by the Borg in *Fly Me to the Moon*
- **Kore Soong (and androids)**
- **Narek**
- **Raffi Musiker**
- **Chris Rios**
- **Elnor**
- **Laris**
- Tallinn - disguised as a Human in *Farewell*
- **Adam Soong**

### Star Trek: Lower Decks

- Beckett Mariner - disguised as an Orion in *We'll Always Have Tom Paris*
- **Brad Boimler**
- D'Vana Tendi - transformed into a giant scorpion in *The Spy Humongous*
- **Sam Rutherford**
- **Carol Freeman**
- Jack Ransom - transformed into a giant head in *Strange Energies*
- **Shaxs**
- **T'Ana**

### Star Trek: Strange New Worlds

- **La'an Noonien-Singh**
- **Erica Ortegas**
- **Joseph M'Benga**
- **Hemmer**
- **Una Chin-Riley**

Comment: Picard - does borgification count?

Comment: Spock - disguised as a Romulan in Unification.   Wesley - evolves into a Traveler. Odo - transformed into a solid, then disguised as a Klingon.

Comment: @Pete was Spock's Romulan disguise anything other than different clothes? Did Wesley's appearance change at all? Odo is already discounted.

Comment: Lower Decks - shall we count the crew of the U.S.S. Alhambra?  https://static.tvtropes.org/trope_videos_transcoded/images/sd/stld_did_you_get_on_the_wrong_ship_0.png   Or excretus of borg?  https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Excretus_of_Borg

Comment: Spock pretended to be human in City On The Edge Of Forever, and The Voyage Home.

Comment: @Pete but did he change his appearance, or did he just wear a hat?

Comment: Quark - becomes human in Far Beyond the Stars. (Also Dukat and Weyoun - regular characters, even if antagonists)

Comment: Spock also becomes Human in Spectre Of The Gun. Sort of. The Earps see him as human, at least.

Comment: @Pete in Far Beyond the Stars isn't it just the usual actors playing different characters in the vision?

Comment: It's a human based upon Quark that appears in a vision. I think it counts. As I think Spock covering up his ears to look human counts.

Comment: For DS9, does Bashir getting replaced by a Changeling count? How about the time Dax used the bodies of the crew as vessels for her past selves?

Comment: Worf changed his appearance during the episode where his step brother beamed people into the holodeck, so he could act as a prophet and guide them to the new land where they could be beamed down to. I can't remember the name of the episode, species, or his brother's name atm.

Comment: At first I wasn't sure The Doctor would count as being transformed in species, being a hologram and thus not being an organism and having no genetic family. But it seems most dictionaries carry a broader definition than that, so it actually does.

Comment: As for Trip, there was the time he became pregnant in [season 1](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unexpected_(episode)). Considering human males can not get pregnant, a fact that was emphasized in the episode, technically, he may not have been completely human at the time.

Comment: Does "Spock's brain" count as a transformation?

Comment: @PeterM into what species?

Comment: @OrangeDog Into a control mechanism.  Technically it isn't a species, but the OP does call out transformations by surgery.

Comment: @NKCampbell - Picard borgification must count I'd assume since Tuvok's and Annika Hansen's Borifications do.

Comment: But if borgification doesn't... Does Tuvok and Neelix combining into a vulaxian count? What about Torres splitting out into human and klingon?

Comment: Ugh, *Threshold,* that *horror show* of an episode. Captain Janeway and Tom Paris making **lizard babies?!**

Comment: I don't know why two people rejected the Tallinn edit. It meets the criteria as far as I can see.

Comment: Genesis........

Comment: @n00dles what about it?

Comment: I'm confused: Why is Christine Chapel listed in "Star Trek: The Animated Series" rather than "Star Trek"?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper because she's not a main cast character in "Star Trek"

Comment: @OrangeDog: According to [MA](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Christine_Chapel#Appearances), she appeared only in 9 (out of 22), which is less than [Arex](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Arex#Appearances) with appearances in 19 episodes. But, granted, who is or is not main cast by production may deviate from how "main" their part is on the actual show.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper being the wife of the creator also helps. She's also main cast in Strange New Worlds, so still counts even if TAS is removed.

Comment: You could argue that Kes was still Kes, she still resembled an Ocampa, just grown up to the next stage of natural development. They recognise her when she comes back in a pretty destructive hissy fit.